# Performance regarding return type for LINQ query compatible with automatic sorting

Tags: winforms, linq-to-sql, sorting, custom-object

this isn't really an issue, but more of a concern that I would appreciate some input on please.

Winforms C# .net3.5[sp1] Visual Studio 2008 using Linq2Sql (more specifically [PLINQO](http://www.plinqo.com)...which is fantastic btw!).  I have a resultset returning +/- 19000 rows of data (with about 80bytes of data per row) and opted to push the data retrieval method to the background and update the UI accordingly.  This works fine.

However, I've noticed some performance differences when using different return-types for my Ling data retrieval method.  I know everyone suggests returning a `List<T>` or `IEnumarable<T>`, and set the DataGridView's datasource to that, but unfortunately it doesn't support sorting natively for objects.  After some digging around I found the `SortableBindingList<T>` on [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms993236.aspx). I applied it, and the Grid took under a second to populate itself - however when I click on a column to sort it, it took a little over a second or so to implement the sort.

I then decided to go the DataTable route, but found out that the ToDataTable method has been removed, but after more digging found a way to implement it on this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx). After applying it, I discovered that the retrieval took about 2 seconds to populate the Grid, but thereafter sorting (on 19000 rows!) was instantaneous!! Naturally I stuck with this approach.

Also keep in mind that I have disabled any in-grid-editing/adding/deleting.  The grid is purely for displaying data.  Any other CRUD operations are provided by dialog forms according to the current selected row (hidden primary key column).

Here is the code I used for both methods:

**1) SortableBindingList**

```
    //declare private member
    private SortableBindingList<PdtAllocation> listAlloc = null;

    private void RefreshData() {
        bcsDataContext ctx = new bcsDataContext();
        try {
            listAlloc = new SortableBindingList<PdtAllocation>(ctx.PdtAllocation.ToList());
        }
        catch (Exception) {
            throw;
        }
        finally {
            ctx.Dispose();
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = listAlloc;
    }
```

**2) CopyToDatatable**

```
    //declare private member
    private DataTable dt = null;

    private void RefreshData() {
        dt = new DataTable();
        bcsDataContext ctx = new bcsDataContext();
        try {
            ctx.PdtAllocation.CopyToDataTable(dt, LoadOption.PreserveChanges);
        }
        catch (Exception) {
            throw;
        }
        finally {
            ctx.Dispose();
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

Now I know this probably seems like an "*asked-and-answered*" case, but I would really appreciate your input, as well as any known issues with going the `CopyToDataTable()` route.

Thank u....and apologies for the looong query!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's my take on your question (going the `SortableBindingList` route).

Did you use a generic, reflection based sorting algorithm? I did this at first and the performance was really bad. Finally I came up with the following solution: provide default sorting in `SortableBindingList<T>` but also leave open the possibility to implement specialized sorting in derived classes.

Here's some code.

In `SortableBindingList<T>.ApplySortCore()`:

```
protected override void ApplySortCore(PropertyDescriptor prop, ListSortDirection direction)
{
    // Check if the sorted property implements IComparable
    ...

    List<T> itemsList = (List<T>)this.Items;

    Comparison<T> comparer = GetComparer(prop);

    itemsList.Sort(comparer);

    if (direction == ListSortDirection.Descending)
    {
        itemsList.Reverse();
    }

    ...
    // Set sort state (is sorted, sort property, sort dir)
}
```

The generic `SortableBindingList<T>` provides a basic, reflection based sorter:

```
protected virtual Comparison<T> GetComparer(PropertyDescriptor prop)
{
    return new Comparison<T>(delegate(T x, T y)
    {
        if (prop.GetValue(x) != null)
            return ((IComparable)prop.GetValue(x)).CompareTo(prop.GetValue(y));
        else if (prop.GetValue(y) != null)
            return -1 * ((IComparable)prop.GetValue(y)).CompareTo(prop.GetValue(x));
        else
            return 0;
    });
}
```

As you can see, `GetComparer()` is virtual, so one can override it in a class derived from `SortableBindingList<T>` in order to provide a *much* faster comparer, tweaked to the type of the property being actually sorted. For example, while the generic comparer sorted (by a `String` property) 10000 records in 4 seconds, the specialized comparer did the same job in 70ms.

```
class CustomerList : SortableBindingList<Customer>
{
    protected override Comparison<Customer> GetComparer(PropertyDescriptor prop)
    {
        Comparison<Customer> comparer = null;
        switch (prop.Name)
        {
            case "FirstName":
                comparer = new Comparison<Customer>(delegate(Customer x, Customer y)
                {
                    string xx = (null == x) ? null : x.FirstName;
                    string yy = (null == y) ? null : y.FirstName;
                    return String.Compare(xx, yy);
                });
                break;
            ...
        }
        return comparer;
    }
}
```

A final note: much of the code posted was copied/inspired from other sources, like SO or Microsoft, so the credit is not mine. My only contribution was virtualizing the comparer but I'm sure a little googling would surface better, earlier solutions based on the same idea.

Comment: Hey Sorin!

"*Did you use a generic, reflection based sorting algorithm?*" no, just used it as is...didnt change a thing.  The code provided by u is great! but any reason why I should NOT be using DataTable??

Comment: Well, my first reaction was "why copy to a DataTable when one could sort the collection at hand?". I don't know. Maybe copying to a DataTable can give some other handy options I can't see right now. Looking forward to see what others have to say about this.

Comment: On its own "ctx.PdtAllocation" returns System.Data.Linq.Table<TEntity>.  Thereafter the choice of 'converting' to some other type remains.  My understanding is that the amount of work taken to ".CopyToDataTable()" is the same as ".ToList()"...so I went with the option that worked out better (on the surface) in the end.  Any further thoughts on this?